# How do I add a TextView to the current layout so I can populate my spinners?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is the layout I am trying to get.  As long as I don't actually try to populate my spinners, everything loads just fine.  Based on what I have found in my searches and the log is that I need to use a TextView with the ArrayAdapter.  Exactly how I do that while preserving the current layout - Spinners and a submit button at the top with a ListView for the returned results below the spinners is what I am having trouble achieving.

Here is my onCreate method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.master);
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        List<Stations> st = db.getAllStations();
        List<CharSequence> stations = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        setList(4, 9);
        for (int i = 0; i < st.size(); i++)
        {
            stations.add(st.get(i).getStation());
        }
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStart);
        Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerEnd);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> SimpleSpinner1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.spinner, R.id.textView1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> SimpleSpinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.spinner, R.id.textView1);
        SimpleAdapter nSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, departures, R.layout.row,
            new String[] {"train", "from", "to"}, new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.TO_CELL});
        for (CharSequence c : stations)
        {
            SimpleSpinner1.add(c);
            SimpleSpinner2.add(c);
        }
    list.setAdapter(nSchedule);
    s2.setAdapter(SimpleSpinner2);
    s1.setAdapter(SimpleSpinner1);

    }
```

master.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerStart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerEnd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerStart" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerEnd"
        android:text="Button" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        layout="@layout/listview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

spinner.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of  `R.id.spinnerStart` /  `R.id.spinnerEnd` you need to pass a textView

EDIT:

Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1);
  spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

textView1 is present in spinner_item layout. Hope this is clear

Comment: So just add a random textview to the layout?  I guess I just don't understand what the TextView has to do with the spinners other then the ArrayAdapter constructor is asking for one.

Comment: I changed R.id.spinnerStart to R.id.TRAIN_CELL which is a text view.  I now get a NullPointerException that occurs in the ArrayAdapter class.  See attached Logcat added to the end of my question.  Also the R.id.TRAIN_CELL has been updated in my question code to reflect.

Comment: main.xml is not the layout which has to be used to display the spinner content.

for example :
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);


spinner_item is a xml file which has textview1 in it.

Comment: Ok, so I created a file called spinner.xml with a textview1 in it.  I think I understand what the ArrayAdapter is doing now and why it needs the textview.  The textview is how it is displaying the individual elements of the spinner.  I ended up creating a new main layout because of some undesirable interaction between the spinners and the listView elements.  The above is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// set id for spinner
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
// prepare a list 
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
// set adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// set adapter to spinner   
spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```